# estimate/solving an linear system of equations with thousands of variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have thousands of equations like this:

```
x10 + x91  + x20  + C1 ~= Z1
x45 + x906 + x535 + C2 ~= Z3
```

in general:

```
X1  + Xn2  + .... + Xn  + Cn ~= Zn
```

and as I mentioned in the title. I have thousands of variables.
now I want to estimate each X

### The real problem:

I have thousands of packages and their weights.
each package consists of a few items and package cardboard and foam peanuts ( hence the **C** in the equation).
I know each package items. now I want to calculate/estimate each item weight

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know C and Z?

Comment: Each package consists of a few items?  Then most of the coefficients in each equation are 0?  That is what is called a "sparse" system.  Try googling "sparse linear systems" or "sparse matrices" for suggestions.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don't know C. but I know Z ( Z is the total weight of each package and C is package cardboard's weight which I'm not interested in )

Comment: Even if the system is dense, you should be able to solve a 1000x1000 system almost instantly on your computer using numpy or MATLAB.

Comment: @tch actually it's 300 000 x 300 000

Comment: In that case you probably won't be able to use a dense solver on your laptop, but if the system is sparse enough you can probably use a sparse solver (from scipy for instance).